# I am unable to install the ADT into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, adt

I am trying to install the android developer's kit into Eclipse (Version: Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149) on a machine running Windows 7, sp1. I already have the latest JDK installed from its site.

When I try to install the ADT, the install fails and reports back:

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
  Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be foundCannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
  Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found
```

Any and all suggestions are welcomed and tried.

Regards,

Steve O'Sulivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on a non-administrator user profile? You most likely have eclipse installed in your program files folder and it's being blocked by windows access controls. You can install eclipse to the C:/ rather than C:/Program Files.

Fixes:
Run eclipse as administrator.
Give the eclipse folder write permission for all users.
Install eclipse to the C:/ rather than C:/Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop EVERYTHING in the c:/ even the eclipse and then flow the right steps as usual.
I had so many errors but that was the solution of them all ;)

good luck :)